# C++ Function Pointer as Argument

Tags: c++, function, pointers, arguments

I have tried multiple google searches and help guides, but I'm out of ideas on this one.  I have a function pointer that I am using as an argument for another function.  Both functions are within the same class.  However, I keep getting type conversion errors.  I'm sure this is just a syntax problem, but I can't understand what the correct syntax is.  Here is a simplified version of my code:

## Header File

```
#ifndef T_H
#define T_H

#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

namespace test
{

class T
{
public:
    T();
    double Sum(std::complex<double> (*arg1)(void), int from, int to);
    int i;
    std::complex<double> func();
    void run();
};

}
#endif // T_H
```

## Source File

```
#include "t.h"

using namespace test;
using namespace std;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
T::T()
{
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
double T::Sum(complex<double>(*arg1)(void), int from, int to)
{
    complex<double> out(0,0);

        for (i = from; i <= to; i++)
        {
            out += arg1();
            cout << "i = " << i << ", out = " << out.real() << endl;
        }

    return out.real();
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
std::complex<double> T::func(){
    complex<double> out(i,0);
    return out;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
void T::run()
{
    Sum(&test::T::func, 0, 10);
}
```

Whenever I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
no matching function for call to 'test::T::Sum(std::complex<double> (test::T::*)(),int,int)'
note:  no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::complex<double> (test::T::*)()' to 'std::complex<double>(*)()'
```

Any advice appreciated.  Or at least a link to a thorough site on how to use function pointers.  I am using Qt Creator 2.6.2, compiling with GCC.

Comment: Thats not just any old function. Its a *member* function.

Comment: Change `complex<double>(*arg1)(void)` to `complex<double>(T::*arg1)(void)`

Comment: And I believe you'd call it like `out += (this->*arg1)();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code itself is a bit messy, I'll only correct the grammer to make it work.

firstly, you shall change the function prototype from

```
double Sum(std::complex<double> (*arg1)(void), int from, int to);
```

to

```
double Sum(std::complex<double> (T::*arg1)(void), int from, int to);
```

Meaning that it is a pointer to class T's member.

Then, when calling the function, you cant just `arg1()`,

```
for (i = from; i <= to; i++)
{
    out += arg1();
    cout << "i = " << i << ", out = " << out.real() << endl;
}
```

you have to use `(this->*arg1)()`;

```
for (i = from; i <= to; i++)
{
    out += (this->*arg1)();
    cout << "i = " << i << ", out = " << out.real() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Now the code doesn't support the plain use-case of passing a normal function anymore.

Comment: Good point.  For the moment, I only need it to work for member functions.  At a later revision, I may add an overload to allow normal functions.  Possibly as a template function for maximum flexiblity.  But I still have several thousand lines of code to debug after this.  For now, I plan to keep it simple.

Answer (score 3):

Your Sum function expects pointer to a function. And then you try to call it with a pointer to a member function. Learn about pointers to members.

Answer (score 1):

How to pass functions as arguments in C++? In general, use a template, unless you have very compelling reasons not do it.

```
template<typename Func>
void f(Func func) {
  func(); // call
}
```

On the call side, you can now throw in a certain amount of objects (not just pointers to functions):

Functors;

```
struct MyFunc {
  void operator()() const {
    // do stuff
  }
};

// use:
f(MyFunc());
```

Plain functions:

```
void foo() {}

// use
f(&foo) {}
```

Member functions:

```
struct X {
  void foo() {}
};

// call foo on x
#include <functional>
X x;
func(std::bind(&X::foo, x));
```

Lambdas:

```
func([](){});
```

If you really want a compiled function and not a template, use `std::function`:

```
void ff(std::function<void(void)> func) {
  func();
}
```

Comment: Turns out that I needed to learn about using pointers to member functions.  I also like the idea of using a template which would allow for lambdas.  I tried lambdas earlier, and ran into compiler errors.  I think for the moment, I will simply write the function to allow pointers to member functions.  In a later revision, I may add an overload that uses Sum() as a template function to allow lambdas.  Thanks all for the great advice.

Comment: @NicholasBarczak You might want to check if your compiler supports C++11. gcc upwards of 4.7 does, clang upwards of 3.3 as well. Both require the -std=c++11 argument to be passed. MSVC kind of supports it, but there is the mess of versions and compiler pre-releases and what not.